# Basic MIPS explanation

Tags: mips

I am new to MIPS and I am working with the QtSpim.

On my first example the console prints 5.

```
li $a0, 5
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

In this example it will print *hello*

```
str: .asciiz "hello"

li $v0, 4
la $a0, str
syscall
```

When I changed the *1* to *4* on example 1 I didn't get the *5* as a result.
When I changed the 4 to 1 on example 2 I didn't get the *hello* as a result.

What is the purpose of **1** in

```
li $v0, 1
```

and what is the purpose of 4 in

```
li $v0, 4
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

syscall call a different function depending on the value in `$v0`: 1 for print-int, 4 for print-string. They print the value stored with `li` (load immediate) instruction in `$a0`.
Refer to [a tutorial on MIPS](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm) for further information.

Comment: Thank yoi for this. and `li $v0, 10` ends the function?

Comment: Yes, it's the exit code. In assembly you don't have a real way to pass parameters to function: either they take value on stack or they refer (like syscall) to values stored in particular registries.

Comment: How can I contact you personally for a paid project?

Comment: Well, I'm not in the assembly field it's just an hobby! I work as an enterprise consultant, but anyway really thank you for the offer!

Comment: One last question.. What is the purpose of `$v0` in `li $v0, 4`. Can I use `li $t0, 4` instead ?

Comment: Nope, $v0 is used by syscall to decide which function call. In this case you have the string and per documentation the function print-string is called when the value in registry $v0 is 4. This is why you can't use $t0: in that case you cannot say to syscall where is the value to decide which function call.

Comment: Hi again, you may be interested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158409/big-endian-to-little-endian-using-mips-without-logical-operations