# Big Endian to Little Endian using MIPS without logical operations?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am using MIPS (QtSpim) to covert a 32bit word from Big Endian to Little Endian. What I show below is checked and correct. However I would like to know what other ways will let me do the conversion. I though only by using rotates and shifts, but I didn't manage to do it without logical operations.

So my question is, can it be done without logical operations?

[image]

```
li $t0,0x12345678     # number to be converted supposed to be in $t0
rol $t1,$t0,8         
li $t2,0x00FF00FF     # $t2 contains mask 0x00FF00FF
and $t3,$t1,$t2     # byte 0 and 2 valid
ror $t1,$t0,8       
not $t2,$t2        # $t2 contains mask 0xFF00FF00
and $t1,$t1,$t2     # byte 1 and 3 valid
or $t3,$t3,$t1      # little endian-number in $t3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes a solution that does not use logical operators. However, it is just a hack:

```
  li $t0,0x12345678   # number to be converted supposed to be in $t0

  swl $t0, scratch+3
  lwl $t1, scratch    # Load MSB in LSB
  lwr $t1, scratch+3  # Load LSB in MSB


  swl $t0, scratch+2
  lwr $t2, scratch    # Swap second and
  lwl $t2, scratch+1  # third bytes

  sw $zero, scratch 
  lwl $t2, scratch    # Leave MSB and LSB in zero
  lwr $t2, scratch+3
  addu $t3, $t1, $t2  # Add partial results to get final result

 .data 0x2000  # Where to locate scratch space (4 bytes)
scratch:
 .space 4
```

Input is `$t0`, partial results are in `$t1` and `$t2` and final result is in `$t3`. It also uses 4 bytes of memory (located at `scratch`)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have accepted your answer. A last yes/no question, can this be solved only with logical operations?

Comment: @Kaoukkos: I believe you cannot solve it using **only** logical operations, because you need some means to move (shift) bytes.